# How to run a PyPi package command on Python

Tags: python, shell, twitch, os.system, vod

I want to use the `twitch-dl` package from PyPi. After installing it, the idea is to basically run it on the terminal like this:

```
twitch-dl download <twitch-vod-url>
```

And it works well when running on the terminal but my goal is to run this command inside my Python script:

```
os.system('twitch-dl download <twitch-vod-url>`')
```

All I get is `256` as my output when I run this code. It does not download anything.

Comment: Can you try running it from terminal and share what error code you get?

Comment: @AnkurSaxena There is no error. It runs well on the terminal.

Comment: If your goal is to use the `twitch-dl` library itself within your code, it's usually advisable to import functions/classes from the package directly in your code rather than trying to invoke the CLI. I took a look, and it doesn't appear the author has provided any documentation for using the package directly from within your code. However, I would take a look at the source code and see if you can import whatever functions you need. I'd start here: https://github.com/ihabunek/twitch-dl/blob/master/twitchdl/download.py. The `download_file` and `download_files` functions look promising.

Comment: @yanniskatsaros Thank you. I'll take a look but I also want to make this work.

Comment: @oo92, I see. In that case, I suggest you take a look at [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) which allows you to execute a child program in a new process.

Comment: @yanniskatsaros I tried that. Unless I got the syntax wrong. subprocess.Popen did not work.

Comment: Both `subprocess.run(['twitch-dl' ,'download' ,'http://www.twitch.tv/videos/883439761'])` and `subprocess.Popen(['twitch-dl' ,'download' ,'http://www.twitch.tv/videos/883439761'])` do not work

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```py
import subprocess
import twitchdl...

vod_url = "<twitch-vod-url>"
command = f"twitch-dl download {vod_url}"

try:
    subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    print("Download completed")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Download failed error code as {e.returncode}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).